# Async variable appearing empty in conditional logic, yet it is present in console logs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous

I'm a bit stumped as to how to correct this async issue. I have data `vocab` that I *know* I am successfully populating based on data from my database. However, at this time I can't quite figure out how to properly access that async data later in my function. Thoughts?

```
export const fsFetchLessonVocab = async (
  language: string,
  id: string,
  includeTranslations?: boolean,
  translationLanguage?: string
) => {
  const lesson = await fsFetchLesson(language, id).then((res) => res);
  const lessonContent = await lesson.contentID.get();

  const vocab = [];

  try {
    await lessonContent.data().words.forEach((word) => {
      word.get().then((res) => {
        vocab.push({ ...res.data(), id: res.id });
      });
    });
    return vocab;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error retrieving content', error);
  }

  if (includeTranslations) {
    console.log('inbound vocab', vocab); //  YES - vocab array has content
    if (vocab.length) {
      //  NO - vocab is an empty array.
      const translations = await vocab.forEach((word) => {
        console.log('word', word);
      });
      console.log('translations', translations);
    }
  }
}
```

---

> more details

```
const vocab = [];

  try {
    await lessonContent.data().words.forEach((word) => {
      word.get().then((res) => {
        vocab.push({ ...res.data(), id: res.id });
      });
    });
    return vocab;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error retrieving content', error);
  }
```

^ This block is working as expected. My content document is reached, and I iterate through the response array of words, finding each reference and pushing it into `vocab`.

```
  if (includeTranslations) {
    console.log('inbound vocab', vocab); // Populated array
    if (vocab.length) {
      // Empty array
      const translations = await vocab.forEach((word) => {
        console.log('word', word);
      });
      console.log('translations', translations);
    }
  }
```

^ the array `vocab` is appearing populated in the `console.log()`, however it's appearing empty within the `if()` block.

---

**Continued:**

I've found that whilte `vocab` shows and array with content, `vocab.length` shows `0` in the log.

Comment: I believe chrome's console will reflect updates made to arrays that are logged, after they are logged. So the fact that vocab is appearing populated in console.log() doesn't mean that it had values in it when it was logged. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316)

Answer (score 1):

try maybe this code:

```
try {
  await Promise.all(
    lessonContent.data().words.map(async word => {
      const res = await word.get();
      vocab.push({ ...res.data(), id: res.id });
    }),
  );
  return vocab;
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error retrieving content', error);
}
```

if `res.data()` is async as well you need to await for that as well

Comment: are you awaiting for fsFetchLessonVocab ?